# Fixing up a 1920 Rowhouse - second floor ceiling insulation

Tags: insulation, ceiling, lath-and-plaster

So - I thinking of pulling the whole plaster and lath ceiling down in a second floor bedroom and putting up drywall and thought might be a good opportunity to insulate between the roof and the ceiling.  I think I only have ~24 inches between the two (~30" including the joists)  What would be the best insulating method here?

Or should I just throw up some sheet rock over the lath, avoid the mess and call it a day.

Comment: What slope does the existing roof have? Is the "attic" space vented?

Comment: It's a flat roof slightly sloped I assume. Sorry.  There are two vents on the facade nothing forcing it out just what appears to 2 6"x6" grates in front a few inches below the roof trim/capping.

Comment: Whichever you do were you planning on using 1 x 3" strapping to screw the drywall to? http://www.oneprojectcloser.com/strapping-ceiling-joists-ceiling-drywall-installation-prep/

Comment: No - I wasn't. 
The internet is a blessing and a curse.   I read so many articles/comments saying that just put drywall over the sheet rock and use longer screws.  Others say pull it all down and strap it to level it out. Causing me to be indecisive and my wife is losing patience as well.